# C++ SQLite return some values?

Tags: c++, sql, sqlite, parsing, recv

I am coding a serverside program that uses SQLite. When a client logs in, I want to get its informations from a `Userinfo` table.

Its columns are

- Userno(int),
- money(int),
- bankmoney(int),
- gender(string),
- name,
- surname

I want to write these informations to a user structure

```
struct userstruct
{
  int userno;
  int money;
  int bankmoney
  ....
}
```

When a user logs in I want to create a new struct and set infos of user from this table via SQLite.

Comment: What's your problem? If you want  to do so, just go for it.

Comment: I dont know how to do it via callback function.

Comment: If you "don't know how", hire a professional developer. If you want *help to do it*, post your best try and what is stopping you from proceeding.

Comment: @nvoigt ok ok ok ok

Comment: I reformatted the question for better readability. I hope that I inferred the correct interpretation of the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following:

```
static int callback(void *data, int argc, char **argv, char **azColName)
```

- `void *data` - can be used to give pointer to an object - aka this, or anything else,  can be null
- `int argc` - column count - number of selected records
- `char **argv` - ARRAY of column values.
- `char **azColName` - ARRAY of column names

btw:  better use prepare - bind - step, like the following sample, this way it works without a callback:

```
sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, "select distinct name, age from demo where age > ? order by 2,1;", -1, &stmt, NULL);

sqlite3_bind_int(stmt, 1, 16);                                                                  /* 1 */

while ( (rc = sqlite3_step(stmt)) == SQLITE_ROW) {                                              /* 2 */
    printf("%s is %d years old\n", sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 0), sqlite3_column_int(stmt, 1));  /* 3 */
}
```